# What is most SEO optimized image HTML code for?

Tags: html, seo

so far i was doing it like this:

```
<a href="http://domain.com" title="Keyword"><img src="image.png" alt="Keyword" /></a>
```

Now, i discovered that images can have title attribute too:

```
<a href="http://domain.com" title="Keyword"><img src="image.png" alt="Keyword" title="Keyword"/></a>
```

Is there any other optimization i could pull off to boost image links value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of the `alt` attribute as an alternative text replacement for the image. Imagine for a moment that you had to describe the image to someone who could not see it. That is the sort of information you should be conveying in the `alt` attribute.

Similar to the `alt` attribute, `title` is used for the same purpose. It helps to convey extra information about an element. You can apply the `title` attribute to *most* elements but you *must* give all your images an `alt` attribute.

In my opinion, having both an `alt` and a `title` on an image is redundant, especially if they are conveying the same information.

Comment: greenie, dont you thing those attributes are the extra space for targedet keywords even thought they're considered to be used as description method. For instance, if i had a client, say a insurance company i would put it this way: <a href="http://www.realinsurance.com.au/" title="Life Insurance - Real Insurance"><img src="logo.png" alt="Life Insurance - Real Insurance" title="Real Insurance Logo" /></a> would that method be good solution?

Comment: Sort of along the right lines yes. The "Life Insurance - Real Insurance" title on the link is good because you are describing what the site is that you are linking to. I'd then consider removing the title attribute from the image element because firstly, you're just repeating what alt says and secondly, you already have the same title on the link. As that link is surrounding the image, web crawlers would probably see the two as related items.

Comment: And in response to the first part of your reply, no I don't consider alt and title places to put keywords. I don't believe that web crawlers look for keywords the same way they used to in the early days of the web. These days I think they are much more semantic and look for the meanings in phrases and sentences. You should focus on writing as descriptively as possible without writing extensively.

Answer (score 6):

I think that's the best you can do really, someone told me to try and make image names as descriptive as possible, for instance:

`image_001.jpg --> honda_accord_2009.jpg`

Granted `image.png` is just an example, but it might apply.

That's all I could think of.

Answer (score 2):

I would have to say yes, the title tag would add value to your SEO. Check this link for full details - http://www.seocentral.com/tutorials/alt-title-attributes.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't over-optimize your links and/or images.
As other users pointed out every image should contain an alt-attribute.
On decorative images the alt tag should be places but it should be empty since it doesn't convey any information.

The alt tag should describe the meaning of the image within the current context. Imagine trying to explain the image to a blind person. If you can't come up with a good way to explain why the image is relevant there the alt tag should be empty (if the image should be placed there at all)

Check out this article for more information on that:
http://www.userfocus.co.uk/articles/alt_text.html

The title tag creates this little popup when you hover over the link or image for about a second. This should be used to give the describe the image and might be a better place to put a keyword.

What you also missed in the question is the filename. If the image is relevant to the topic of the page you could use keyword.jpg or something.

This would also help it in image search engines.